# Synchronize with only published nodes

Tags: drush

We are going to have a "staging" server where all edits will be made. We are going to push to the cloud production server with Drush sync. I know there is a way to exclude tables, but is there a way to only push nodes and field data from published nodes/revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing all the options listed on https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/sql/sql-sync for `drush sql-sync` command, it seems you can apply limitations on a table level only. So you might want to build a custom code for syncing data as there is no way to push nodes and field data using Drush sync per their published statuses.

Comment: It’s also exceptionally difficult due to the level of tables involved and other considerations.